# shuffling vector array with tiles

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, sfml

I am working on a school project. It is a tile moving game, I have the tiles on the screen taken out from a tiles vector array.

I am trying to shuffle the tiles and put them into another vector array called shuffledTiles and then show them on the screen but the code I wrote just works with only one tile. Can anybody help me what I have done on the wrong way. I am a beginner programmer.

This is the code I have for shuffling:

```
void Game::ShuffleTiles()
{
    /* THIS FUNCTION IS TO CHOOSE A RANDOM TILE FROM THE TILES VECTOR STORAGE, TAKE ITS POSITION AND PUT IT INTO A NEW ARRAY CALLED SHUFFLED TILES, SET ITS POSITION TO THE 
    POSITION SAVED INTO A TEMPORARY VECTOR2F variable */

    // take items from 0 to 15 ->> 16 items
    for (int i = 0; i < this->tiles.size(); i++)
    {
        // setting the random seed by time to make sure different random number is given every time 
        srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

        // Vector2f variable for storing the position of the random selected tile
        sf::Vector2f randTilePosXY;

        // integer for the random number between 0 and 16
        int randomNumber = rand() % this->tiles.size();

        // console out to see which random number is selected
        std::cout << "Random Number: " << randomNumber << std::endl;

        // taking the randomly selected tile's position and saving it into the Vector2f variable
        randTilePosXY == this->tiles[randomNumber].getPosition();

        //Showing the random tile's X and Y positions
        std::cout << "Random Number X and Y: " << std::stringstream(randTilePosXY) << std::endl;
        // putting the randomly selected tile to the end of the new shuffledTiles vector array
        this->shuffledTiles.push_back(this->tiles[randomNumber]);

        // setting the position of item in the shuffledTiles vector storage under the index number
        this->shuffledTiles[i].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(randTilePosXY));


    }
```

And I want to show them with this code:

```
for (auto& s : this->shuffledTiles)
    {
        this->window->draw(s);
        this->window->draw(emptyTile);
    }
```

The emptyTile is a tile on the bottom right corner and its position I do not want to change because it is not necessary.

Thank you for the help.

Tamas

Comment: Try `assert(this->tiles.size() == 16);`

Comment: What is assert?

Comment: Should I put it into the for loop or outside of it?

Comment: `#include <cassert>` and the assert before the loop to confirm that tiles actually contains 16 elements.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: Actually, you should be seeing "Random Number: " 16 times in the output, so you don't need the assert.

Comment: Can I show the Vector2f X and Y variables in a string on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you think your code does one thing when, in fact, it doesn't do what you think it does *at all*. What you're doing is essentially:

```
// Step 1. Pick a tile from the existing set of tiles randomly.
int randomNumber = rand() % this->tiles.size();

// Step 2. Remember the randomly chosen tile's position
randTilePosXY == this->tiles[randomNumber].getPosition();

// Step 3. Copy the randomly chosen tile into a separate vector.
// THIS WILL COPY ALL INFORMATION OF THE TILE, INCLUDING ITS POSITION!
this->shuffledTiles.push_back(this->tiles[randomNumber]);

// Step 4. Copy AGAIN the POSITION INFORMATION.
// THIS STEP IS COMPLETELY USELESS AS YOU JUST OVERWRITE THE POSITION WITH THE SAME POSITION.
this->shuffledTiles[i].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(randTilePosXY));
```

Your "shuffled tiles" vector is nothing more than the exact same information, just in a different order. Here's what's happening:

```
vector<tile> tiles = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}}; // Three tiles at different positions.

// "Shuffle" the tiles...

shuffledTiles = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {0, 0}};
```

What have you shuffled here? Whether you print `tiles` or `shuffledTiles`, can you see how the result will be *exactly the same*?

Edit: as an aside, this line of code: `srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));` should appear only once in your entire program. Put it at the top of your `main` function. The random generator only needs to be seeded once.

Comment: I have a vector array filled up with tiles and set the positions of these tiles to certain positions, and I am trying to copy the items from the tiles vector array with choosing a random item, saving its position and put that tile into a new vector array with the saved position into the end of the new array. Basically this is how my logic went.

Comment: @Tamas35 What are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a new vector array with tiles in it on random positions and show them on the screen.

Comment: @Tamas35 Please update your question with what you are trying to achieve. If possible, show the "before" and "after" for the desired outcome. Second, do you understand what I have written?

Comment: I put the random generator into the main. I enclosed a picture of what it looks like now.

Comment: I have a before and after picture now

Answer (score 0):

[This is how it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LjMm.png)

I do not understand what you are explaining completely sorry.

And this is what I want to achieve, but different positions every time when the program loads in.

[Shuffled Tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09sHD.png)

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: Can anybody help me with this please?